# Android App - Screen Size not Scaling after creating different layout folders

Tags: java, android, size, screen, scale

I have been trying to make my Android app scale to different screens. Therefore I read about this in the Android guides and found that I needed to make different size images and different layout folders.

I made different layout folders and played around with the XML files until I got it to display something I was happy with on a different size screen.

Also, I changed my images into the different formats (e.g. xhdpi and mdpi). I was a little confused about this, since I don't know what pixel sizes are what in comparison to mdpi (for example is 100x100 an xhdpi or an mdpi?)

Anyway, when I run my app on different size phones it doesn't change layout. Is there something I need to write in my java code (in the activity file) to make it change layout?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read this: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: Yes, I have done everything the guides say. It still doesn't seem to work. Thanks for trying to help though :)